# How to fix "Azure Function Output Adapter failed to write events"

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-suite

I have in my Azure IoT architecture a Stream Analytics (SA) connect to an Azure Function.

Sometimes I have this error of my SA:

```
"Send Events: Azure Function Output Adapter failed to write events"
```

and in the JSON message of the error I find this description:

```
"Message": "Failed to write events. Error encountered after writing [0] batches [...]
"Type": "AzureFunctionOutputAdapterFailure"
```

I don't have error on the Azure Function but it stopped work.
Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Comment: This can be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851553/an-error-occurred-send-events-azure-function-output-adapter-failed-to-write-eve

Comment: I set the correct version of the TLS of the Azure Suite, but it doesn't work yet. It seems related only to the Stream Analytics

Comment: @davide - does the Azure Functions code compile with no errors? and have you unit tested the function independently? You shouldn't have to change the TLS version any longer.

Comment: @SidRamadoss It happened sometimes so it's very strange. I think the Azure Function it's too complex. I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices to re-write the structure of the function to an Azure Logic App.